# Python: evaluate a consonant or vowel

Tags: python

I can't figure out why when I enter the word 'fish' for original its printing vowel.

```
#Begin program

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower() #make sure original is lowercase
    first = word[0]
    if first == 'a' or 'e':
        print "vowel"
    else:
        print "consonant"
else:
    print 'empty'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if first == 'a' or 'e'
```

Change it to

```
if first == 'a' or first == 'e':
```

Or

```
if first in ('a', 'e'):
```

Your if statement is evaluating to `True` since you are doing a boolean OR with a True value (`'e'`).

Non empty strings in Python evaluate to `True`.

```
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('a')
True
```

Hence, your code gets evaluated as

```
if (first == 'a') or True:
```

which is always evaluated to `True` and hence the `if` statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Your if condition is wrong. Specifically,

```
if first == 'a' or 'e':
```

won't work. It needs to be

```
if first == 'a' or first == 'e':
```

The original statement evaluates like this:

```
if (first == 'a') or ('e'):

if (False) or (True):
```

Here's an [explanation of truth](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html) values in Python. Note that characters evaluate as true.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `if first == 'a' or 'e':` is being treated like `if (first == 'a') or ('e'):`

Since 'e' is truthy, the `or` is returning `true`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such situations and to make your code more clear, write

```
if first in ('a', 'e'):
    ...
```

or

```
if first in 'ae':
    ...
```